# Pressing the "Opt" key to show Lauchpad

Tags: keyboard, launchpad

In KDE Plasma I was able to press the Win key and the overview menu has been shown with my apps, favorites, recent, etc.

I would like a similar behavior for my Mac - just because of the muscle memory.

So, I would like to press the Opt key and after the release it would show the Launchpad.

But at the same time I still want to retain the ability to use the Opt key in combinations with other keys to trigger shortcuts, etc.

Any idea how can it be done?

Comment: In general, single-key shortcuts are not supported, other than for F-keys/Special Functions. Trying to override this for a key which would normally be a modifier… how do you decide [or code] how long it should wait to see if you are actually going to press another key? I'd just bite the bullet & use the key already made for this, the Special Function on F4. The Mac has no equivalent to the Windows or Menu key.

Comment: Vim people use caps lock as ctrl when pressed with other key and esc when alone all the time. It's not so unique, at least in the Linux world.

Comment: macOS is not Linux.

Comment: Both are based on Unix though. Are you claiming it's impossible to do on Mac? Have you ever tried it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no system-wide option for this.
You can use [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) to achieve such behavior.

To change the Karabiner configuration open **~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json** file and add the next content to **rules** array (separate rules by a comma if you have a couple of them):

```
{
    "description": "Open Launchpad if left Option pressed alone",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "left_option",
                "modifiers": {
                    "optional": [
                        "any"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "left_option",
                    "lazy": true
                }
            ],
            "to_if_alone": [
                {
                    "key_code": "launchpad"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```

Karabiner applies config dynamically, so you should be able to use new behavior right after saving the config file.